# Reading text file and checking column count is the same for all rows

Tags: c#, winforms, file, readfile

I have a txt file which contains n numbers of row and each row has n number of columns with one delimiter.

How to read that txt file line by line and check all the rows has same columns. if any row has extra column then show the row number with text.

suppose I have below rows in my txt file

> 147789-00,67,KB08,2007,12,0.000 ,0.000 ,0.000
>
> A22951,67,RN3W,2007,12,0.000 ,0.000 ,0.000
>
> 946106-00,67,RN1W,2007,12,0.000 ,0.000 ,0.000,000
>
> A22951,67,RN3W,2007,12,0.000 ,0.000 ,0.000

out of 4 row 3rd row has extra column, same way there could be some one rows can have extra columns. that extra columns I want to find. or I can say if any rows has extra delimiter then it will show the row number with text.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"c:\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
{
       // how to match the columns    
}
```

Am I going in right path.. Please someone help me.

Comment: What do you mean by extra column? Having n+1 columns or something like that? Share some sample data to help us understand.

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: I would also recommend a look at CSVHelper -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/ they have a lot of basic functionality you wouldn't have to do by yourserlf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *don't know* actual number of columns but want to ensure that this unknown number is the same for all the lines:

```
  char delimiter = ',';
  int columnCount = -1; // or put the number if it's known

  var errors = File
    .ReadLines(@"c:\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8) // UTF-8 is default and can be skipped
    .Select((line, index) => {
      int count = line.Split(delimiter).Length;

      if (columnCount < 0)
        columnCount = count;

      return new {
        line = line,
        count = count,
        index = index
      };
    })
    .Where(chunk => chunk.count != columnCount)
    .Select(chunk => String.Format("Line #{0} \"{1}\" has {2} items when {3} expected",
       chunk.index + 1, chunk.line, chunk.count, columnCount));

 // To check if file has any wrong lines:
 if (errors.Any()) {
   ...
 }

 // To print out a report on wrong lines
 Console.Write(String.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, errors));
```

Comment: the error message will show when row will count from 0 what about the end user, they will start count from 1 not 0

Comment: @Rocky: if you want start count from `1`, not from `0`, just add `+1` (see my edit). Same for line index

Comment: it should be chunk.index + 1 not chunk.count + 1, columnCount + 1

Comment: @Rocky: Right; need more coffee :)

Comment: @Rocky: then put the number into `columnCount` instead of current `-1`: e.g. `int columnCount = 8`;

Comment: yeah got it and done as well. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What if provided delimiter does not match with text file delimiter?

Comment: @Rocky: then you'll get wrong results. I've assumed that you know the delimiter. Change `char delimiter = ',';` if actual delimiter is not comma, e.g. `char delimiter = ';';`.

Comment: Can we add any validation to check if supplied delimiter is not match with file delimiter then show delimiter does not match with file? Please suggest something

Comment: @Rocky: it's hardly a *validation*, it's more a guess, e.g. imagine file line like this: `1,2;3` is it a *comma* or a *semicolon* that's a delimiter? We can *count* supposed delimeters in the 1st file line and then analyze the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

```
char delimiter = ','; // This can be modified 
int numberOfCols = 6; // this will be the number of columns per row

var lines = File
  .ReadLines("Path here")
  .Where(l => l.Split(delimiter).Count() == numberOfCols);
```

This Will   give you a collection that contains row with specified number of cols; To collect the invalid rows you can use the following:

```
var invalidLines = File
    .ReadLines("Path here")
    .Select((l, lineNumber) => new { key = lineNumber, value = l })
    .Where(l => l.value.Split(delimiter).Count() != numberOfCols);
```

Comment: what if I don't know number of columns

Comment: What the system want to do `if You don't know number of columns`

Comment: system has to get the columns based on delimiter.

Comment: Fine; then how you define the term `extra column`

Comment: if any row has extra delimiter that means that line has extra column

Comment: In the given example all rows except 3rd and 4th having 8(`numberOfCols `) columns. that's why you are saying they are having an extra column. will it be `8` all times? specify that number in `numberOfCols`; or tell me how do i get `8`

Comment: exactly 3rd and 4th having numberOfCols is more based on extra delimiter thats what I need to find. @DmitryBychenko is showing the exact example which I am expecting

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\file.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{

}
```

Now, u can split your line with any seprator.